# How do I put a potion effect on a offhand held item? (1.10)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to get that when a apple named leftovers is in my offhand it will give regen 1. So I know how to do it in 1.8 by using the scoreboard objective but when I go in to 1.9 or higher it doesn't work. I need help!

Comment: You should be showing us what you tried that is no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

Type this into the chat:

(1): `/scoreboard objectives add leftovers dummy`

Place one command block containing this command:

(2): `/scoreboard players set @a leftovers 1 {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:apple,tag:{display:{Name:leftovers}}}}`

Add a comparator between the prior and a command block with this command:

(3): `/execute @a[score_leftovers_min=1,score_leftovers=1] ~ ~ ~ effect @a minecraft:regeneration 45 0 true`

Add repeater going to a block.
Place a redstone torch on the side of the block that leads to some redstone and another repeater.

Place these last two command blocks containing these commands after the repeater:

(4): `/scoreboard players set @a[score_leftovers_min=1,score_leftovers=1] leftovers 0`

(5): `/execute @a[score_leftovers_min=0,score_leftovers=0] ~ ~ ~ effect @a minecraft:regeneration 45 0 true`

Your final product should look like:

"[x]>[x]-[ ]i~[x][x]"

With "[x]" = command block, ">" = comparator, "-" = repeater, "i" = redstonetorch,  "~" = redstone, and "[ ]" = a block.

[This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cm2ajLOhpfA) will explain how to do this in more detail if needed. It is long (12:14), but this is only becuase he uses five different examples.

Comment: @pppery Wouldn't using code blocks (4 white spaces at the start of a line) be better? In this case we would likely have to remove the numbers at the beginning of those lines, but they don't actually seem to serve a purpose, so an edit like that should be fine. Or would that change the authors intent?

Comment: @bearb001 What advantage would using code blocks have in this case?

Comment: @pppery In this answer it's not in-line code, so it would make more sense to actually use code blocks, rather than in-line code. And it would look nicer.

Comment: @bearb001 It's an edit that I feel wouldn't improve the post at all. I see no harm in respecting Josiah Panak's decision to number his comments

Comment: @pppery What about putting the numbers on a separate line then? I don't think that your edit harms the post, I just think it could be better. If I thought it would harm the post I would have rejected the edit.

Comment: @bearb001 What you are suggesting appears to me to be formatting tweaks for the sake of formatting tweaks with no actual improvement in readability.

Comment: @pppery Code blocks are usually easier to read. If that wasn't the case, then code blocks wouldn't be a thing, because everyone would just use in-line code for every command, even if it's a completely separate line, as it is the case here. (except for the number)

Comment: @pppery I don't like line breaks in relatively short commands, it's uggly in my opinion and code blocks are better suited. This edit is better than the original and it does improve readability quite a lot. I don't think I should "improve" your edit by doing something that you disagree with, so I approved it. I'm personally unsure if I can/should remove the numbers without changing the authors intent and I can't suggest an edit myself (it would be accepted without peer review), so I will not edit this answer.